# Read and manipulate Sagemaker Json Output

Tags: python, json

I deployed my HuggingFace Transformer model as a batch process on Sagemaker. My output file is an .jsonl.out file and looks like this:

```json
{"SageMakerOutput":[{"label":"LABEL_8","score":0.9152628183364868}],"inputs":"test"}
{"SageMakerOutput":[{"label":"LABEL_8","score":0.9769203066825867}],"inputs":"Alles OK"}
```

The problem now is that I just want the following output:

```
LABEL_8, test
LABEL_8, Alles OK
```

and return it as an .csv or .xlsx! I tried stuff like:

```
batch_transform_result = []
with open(output_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        # converts jsonline array to normal array
        line = "[" + line.replace("[","").replace("]","") + "]"
        batch_transform_result = literal_eval(line)
```

And tried to add more .replace() functions to clean the read in text up but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @soulwreckedyouth ! How should look like your _final_ output? What is about the "conversion to normal array"?

Comment: That would work for me! In a second iteration I would like to transform the output to a dataframe with the 2 columns (Label & text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below can work for you

```
lst = [
    {"SageMakerOutput": [{"label": "LABEL_8", "score": 0.9152628183364868}], "inputs": "test"},
    {"SageMakerOutput": [{"label": "LABEL_8", "score": 0.9769203066825867}], "inputs": "Alles OK"}
]

result = [(entry['SageMakerOutput'][0]['label'],entry['inputs']) for entry in lst]

print(result)
```

output

```
[('LABEL_8', 'test'), ('LABEL_8', 'Alles OK')]
```

Comment: Thanks @balderman for me it raises the following error: TypeError: string indices must be integers. Is that maybe cause its a list in a list? ```['[{"SageMakerOutput":{"label":"LABEL_8","score":0.9152628183364868},"inputs":"test"}\n]',
 '[{"SageMakerOutput":{"label":"LABEL_8","score":0.9769203066825867},"inputs":"Alles OK"}\n]']```

Comment: Yes. You are using list inside list. This is the reason for the exception.