# Cannot remove single quotes from string

Tags: python, list, replace

I got a super weird problem: I got a list of strings which looks like this:

```
batch = ['{"SageMakerOutput":[{"label":"LABEL_8","score":0.9152628183364868},"inputs":"test"}',
 '{"SageMakerOutput":[{"label":"LABEL_8","score":0.9769203066825867},"inputs":"Alles OK"}',
 '{"SageMakerOutput":[{"label":"LABEL_8","score":0.9345938563346863},"inputs":"F"}']
```

In each entry of the list I want to remove the single quotes "'" but somehow I cannot remove it with .replace():

```
for line in batch:
    line = line.replace("'","")
```

I dont get it

Comment: Why not just read it as json? `import json; json.loads(line)`?

Comment: You want to turn valid JSON string into invalid?

Comment: well, there's no single quotes in the string, but there's a lot of double quotes

Comment: `line = line.replace("'","")` isn't going to mutate `batch`. You are simply assigning a different string to the name `line` in the body of the loop, an assignment which doesn't effect the immutable string in `batch`, and which is lost after that pass through the loop.

Comment: @GhostOps, please, [don't suggest `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/4046632) when there are proper tools to deal with this.

Comment: It appears your string contents is json data, why not use json parser to parse it individually as you loop through the list

Comment: @buran but why? itd in-built and the OP is, seems like, just dealing with some simple dictionaries. so thats why i suggested that...

Comment: Check the link in my comment @GhostOp

Comment: Each record is not json valid (missing `]`)

Comment: Textbook XY problem.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/4046632 
@GhostOps

Comment: As @GhostOps mentioned, there are no `'` in your strings to replace. The single quotes are what encloses your string. Answer this: is `"` part of the string `"abc"`? How would you check if `"` were in that string? You'd have to enclose `"` with a quotation mark in order to treat it as a string, yes? Something like `'"' in "abc"`? Do you see now that the enclosing quotes are not actually part of the string?

Comment: @buran thanks for those suggestions man! learnt a lot!

Comment: Oh my bad @GhostOps I glossed right over that comment because I saw somebody telling you not to use `eval()`.

Comment: @ddejohn yeah, just got roasted in the comments for being a noob in python :')

Comment: lol, the `eval()` roast is a rite of passage for Pythoners

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to show you guys the bigger picture and why I am not reading the file in as a json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362508/read-and-manipulate-sagemaker-json-output

Comment: @ddejohn thanks for the explanation but how do I get rid of it then?

Comment: There's nothing to get rid of. What problem are you really trying to solve that requires removing the (nonexistent) single quotes?

Comment: I looked at your other post and am confused. Do you have dictionaries (as your other post suggests) or do you have strings? If you have strings *why not use* `json` to convert the json strings to dictionaries?

Comment: Try: `batch = list(map(json.loads, batch))`. I'm hoping the missing `]}` in each string is a copying error.

Comment: Or it could be a bug in how you're creating the list from the original input data. You should fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so judging by your comments and your other post, it *seems* like what you have are strings, and what you want are dictionaries. I've copied your data from the other post because your data isn't correct in this post (you're missing `]` in this post).

### Solution

```py
import json

batch = ['{"SageMakerOutput":[{"label":"LABEL_8","score":0.9152628183364868}],"inputs":"test"}',
         '{"SageMakerOutput":[{"label":"LABEL_8","score":0.9769203066825867}],"inputs":"Alles OK"}']

batch = [json.loads(b) for b in batch]
```

Output:

```py
[{'SageMakerOutput': [{'label': 'LABEL_8', 'score': 0.9152628183364868}],
  'inputs': 'test'},
 {'SageMakerOutput': [{'label': 'LABEL_8', 'score': 0.9769203066825867}],
  'inputs': 'Alles OK'}]
```

### Explanation

Those objects in `batch` are what are known as [`JSON`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) objects. They're just strings with a very specific structure. They are analogous to Python's `dict` type with some very minor differences and can very easily be converted to Python `dict` objects using Python's built-in `json` module, which automatically translates those minor differences between JSON and Python (e.g., booleans in JSON strings are `true` and `false`, but in Python they need to be `True` and `False`).

### Notes

Advice to OP and future readers: this post is a classic case of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). In the future, try to be more clear about your end goal. Your question in this post isn't actually answerable because it's impossible to do what you were asking.